# unit testing expect interactions

Tags: unit-testing, tcl, expect

Is there a framework for unit testing in expect ?
Specifically, how can I unit test the  interaction in the below proc?

```
proc take_device_offline {device_name} {
    global device_prompt

    send "device offline $device_name"
    expect {
        -re "offline?" {
            send y
            expect $device_prompt
        }
        -re "something else" {
            expect $device_prompt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What _exactly_ are you seeking to test? Expect's targeted quite strongly at handling _integration_ with external things (subprocesses, remote systems, etc.) so _unit_ testing is going to be… well, awkward as such.

Comment: I am expecting to test the regex match , the logic for each step of the interaction, etc - basically I am trying to do Test Driven Development.